# Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type

Tags: c#

I have a problem with this code but I don't have any clue what to do.
Could you help me.

Error is:

> Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for type 'Refleksija.Country'.    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic,
>   Boolean wrapExceptions)    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type)    at Refleksija.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\darko.brakovic\Source\Repos\Refleksija\Refleksija\Program.cs:line
>   14

Code is

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Type countryType = executingAssembly.GetType("Refleksija.Country");
        object countryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(countryType);

        MethodInfo getCountryInfoMethod = countryType.GetMethod("GetCountryInfo");

        string[] parametri = new string[1];
        parametri[0] = "Srbija";

        string CountryInfo = (string)getCountryInfoMethod.Invoke(countryInstance, parametri);

        Console.WriteLine("CountryInfo: = {0}", CountryInfo);

    }
}
class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public Country(string name, int population)
    {
        Name = name;
        Population = population;
    }
    public string GetCountryInfo()
    {
        return "Country " + Name + " has the population of " + Population + ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(countryType);` is trying to call a parameterless constructor, which `Country` doesn't have

Comment: *No parameterless constructor defined for type 'Refleksija.Country'.*

Comment: You have a self explaining error here, you have to pass `object[] args` to `CreateInstance` to invoke the correct constructor

Comment: Why are you using activator to create a class that exists in the namespace? Practice?

Comment: @RonBeyer I would really hope this isn't homework, because if it is, the standards for what they're teaching have declined drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `Activator.CreateInstance` will only work for the case where you have a parameterless constructor (see the compiler error). For your example you can use `GetConstructor` like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Type countryType = executingAssembly.GetType("Refleksija.Country");
        var countryInstance =
            countryType.GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(string), typeof(int)})
                .Invoke(new object[] {"Srbija", 7_000_000});

        MethodInfo getCountryInfoMethod = countryType.GetMethod("GetCountryInfo");

        string CountryInfo = (string) getCountryInfoMethod.Invoke(countryInstance, new object[] { });

        Console.WriteLine("CountryInfo: = {0}", CountryInfo);

    }
}
class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public Country(string name, int population)
    {
        Name = name;
        Population = population;
    }
    public string GetCountryInfo()
    {
        return "Country " + Name + " has the population of " + Population + ".";
    }
}
```

Also note that `GetCountryInfo` was being invoked with parameters, however it's a parameterless method.